# dispatch Event on the most inner element doesn't cause bubbling to upper elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-bubbling

```js
innerDiv = document.getElementById("inner");
innerDiv.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log("PURPLE COLOR DIV");

}

outterDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("outter")[0];
outterDiv.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log("ORANGE COLOR DIV");
};

containerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
containerDiv.onclick = function() {
  console.log("RED COLOR DIV");
}

setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("inner").dispatchEvent(new Event('click'), {
  bubbles: true
}), 2000)
```

```css
.container {
  width: 260px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: maroon;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.outter {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

#inner {
  background: purple;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outter">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PROBLEM**

After setTimeout causes the dispatchEvent to fire, **the Orange and Red color callbacks do not execute**. Why is that so if bubbles property is set to true?
In case of clicking on the UI purple div, the bubbling does its job as supposed.

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/0tko5qwe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the options to the `Event()` constructor itself:

```
new Event('click', { bubbles: true})
```

```js
innerDiv = document.getElementById("inner");
innerDiv.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log("PURPLE COLOR DIV");

}

outterDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("outter")[0];
outterDiv.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log("ORANGE COLOR DIV");
};

containerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
containerDiv.onclick = function() {
  console.log("RED COLOR DIV");
}

setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("inner").dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {
  bubbles: true
})), 500)
```

```css
.container {
  width: 260px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: maroon;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.outter {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

#inner {
  background: purple;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outter">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```